# AudioFlinger [INTEL RESAMPLER] unsupported SR

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I'm using Android's SoundPool to play various samples (128kbs mp3) in a game.  And it all seems to work fine on Nexus 4, HTC Sensation XE, HUDL2.

However on an Acer A1-830, I'm getting a lot of:

```
AudioFlinger [INTEL RESAMPLER] unsupported SR error messages.
```

These happen even when sounds seem to be working.

After a while sounds stop working and I get:

```
AudioStreamOutAlsa write(...) No route available. Generating silence.
```

I'm using:

```
mSoundPool.play(mSoundId, mLeftVolume, mRightVolume, DEFAULT_PRIORITY, mLoop, mRate);
```

I sometimes see the same SR error on the HUDL2 (which is also intel), but sound works fine.

I've upped the maximum streams to 64 (from 16) and this seems to delay the sound not working issue on the Acer.

My questions are:
1) Why am I getting unsupported sample rate errors: I export all audio at the same 128kbs mp3 format?

2) Has anyone found they need more streams available on some devices (16 was fine for my other devices, and rarely are there more than a few sounds playing simultaneously)?

3) Any solutions to the sound stopping?  Anyone experienced this with some devices and not others?

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: _"What does unsupported SR mean?"_ Most likely unsupported _Sample Rate_.

Comment: Thank you, I suppose it wasn't a great question: I should have asked "why am I getting this on some devices?", I'm using mp3s which I thought were pretty much stuck on 44.1khz...  Have ammended questions.